# On mac, phone won't show on chrome remote debugging tools

Tags: google-chrome

I know that remote debugging is deprecated but my colleague needs to use it to debug something in PWA.
On windows, all is fine, I can still access it from chrome://devices/  and it works.

My colleague has a mac and android phone, his phone is connected and the PC sees it, but chrome won't see it, he has the latest version, he tried also Canary. Everything used to work in 2019, but today it's not. How to fix that?

Chrome does not list his phone, he tried 3 different Android phones, two Samsung, and a Huawei.

He has the latest chrome version, he even tried Canary, which is the bleeding edge version. As for the mac, he has MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010), high Sierra.

Comment: It would help if you listed the versions of macOS and Chrome.  Otherwise, this looks like a support problem that you'd need to contact Google.

Comment: @fsb question edited to include those details. As for contacting google, this is not possible, they don't have a support team that answers people. I did ask here though


https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/gv57m7/on_mac_phone_wont_show_on_chrome_remote_debugging/